# Get correct coverage in sonar for unit and integration tests in separate maven modules

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, integration-testing, code-coverage

My project setup is simple (all source available at [github](https://github.com/pmajkutewicz/jacocoITCoverageExample)):

parent
↳ backend
↳ client
↳ integration-tests

And after runing maven:

```
mci sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=12...9
```

I see that unit and integration tests are visible for sonar, but coverage from IT is not.
[image: sonar coverage]
[image: sonar coverage detailed]

For Intelij IDEA `jacoco-it.exec` looks fine:
[image: idea coverage]

I'm assuming that culprit is here:

```
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
[INFO] No JaCoCo analysis of project coverage can be done since there is no class files.
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
```

So I did small [hack](https://github.com/pmajkutewicz/jacocoITCoverageExample/tree/hack) (in short: copied all source files to `integration-test` module):

```
    <properties>
        <sonar.sources>${basedir}/target/copied</sonar.sources>
    </properties>
    [...]
        <!-- hack to generate coverage reports -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${sonar.sources}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/../backend/src/main/java</directory>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${sonar.sources}</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But now all my classes ale duplicated (sonar shows also classes from `../target/copied` dir):
[image: sonar coverage duplicated]

Sonar version: 6.5
Jacoco maven plugin: 0.7.5.201505241946 (also tried lastest 0.7.9)

Any ideas what should I do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I have answer for that question:

1. Report wasn't generated because `post-unit-test` execution was in the wrong phase. Instead of `<phase>test</phase>` I now have `<phase>verify</phase>`
2. I had a wrong goal for `post-integration-test`. The change was from `<goal>report-integration</goal>` to `<goal>report-aggregate</goal>`:

   - [This goal](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html) allows me to create coverage reports when tests are in separate projects from the code under test.
3. Added properties:
   `<jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../integrations-tests/target/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.itReportPath>` and
   `<sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${jacoco.itReportPath},${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec,${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>`

All those chages and update project available on [github](https://github.com/pmajkutewicz/jacocoITCoverageExample)

Answer (score -2):

I use mainly jacoco for coverage. You need to have a few things in place before you start

1. Enable and configure surefire plugin
2. Enable and configure the jacoco plugin

It's a one time configuration that you will build and forget, one of my projects serving as parent enables this feature. Feel free to check it out: 
https://github.com/slixes/parent/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Yes, I have those plugins configured. Surefire runs UT, maven-failsafe-plugin runs IT tests. And configuration for jacoco (pre/post-unit-test and pre/post-integration-test). Is not copied into question because I don't want to make it unreadable.